# HashMap to JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, hashmap

I am very new to this. My application is working fine, except for printing the `HashMap` to `JTable` in `VisaArtiklarWindow`. this has to be done though the controller class. I have tried to use `TableModel` and some other stuff but nothing seems to be working. Any suggestions?

**the UiController:**

```
    public class UiController {

    private NyArtikelWindow nyAW;
private NyKundWindow nyKW;
private NyOrderWindow nyOW;
private VisaArtiklarWindow nyVAW;
private VisaOrdrarWindow nyVOW;
private SokKundWindow nyVSW;
private MainWindow nyMW;

private Controller controller;

public UiController(Controller newController) {

    This.controller=newController;
    nyMW = new MainWindow(controller,this);
    nyKW= new NyKundWindow (controller, this);
    nyOW= new NyOrderWindow(controller, this);
    nyVAW= new VisaArtiklarWindow(controller, this);
    nyVOW = new VisaOrdrarWindow(controller, this);
    nyVSW = new SokKundWindow(controller, this);

}


public void setVisibleOnMain(){
    nyMW.setVisibleOn();
}

public void setVisibleOffMain() {
    nyMW.setVisibleOff();
}

public void setVisibleOnKund() {
    nyKW.setVisibleOn();
}

public void setVisibleOnArtikel() {
    nyAW.setVisibleOn();
}

public void setVisibleOnOrder() {
    nyOW.setVisibleOn();
}

public void setVisibleOnVisaArtikel() {
    nyVAW.setVisibleOn();
}

public void setVisibleOnVisaOrder() {
    nyVOW.setVisibleOn();
}

public void setVisibleOnSokKund() {
    nyVSW.setVisibleOn();
}
```

}

**Controller:**

```
public class Controller {

private ArtikelReg ar;
private UiController uiController;
private KundReg kr; 
private KundOrderReg or;

public Controller() { 
    uiController = new UiController(this);
    ar = new ArtikelReg(this);
    kr = new KundReg(this);
    or = new KundOrderReg(this);    

    uiController.setVisibleOnMain();
}

public void addKund (int nyttKundnr, String nyttPersorgnr,
        String nyttNamn, String nyttKontaktperson,
        String nyttAdress, int nyttPostnr,
        String nyttOrt, int nyttTelefonnr,
        String nyttEpost) {
    Kund nyKund = new Kund(nyttKundnr, nyttPersorgnr, nyttNamn, nyttKontaktperson, nyttAdress, nyttPostnr, nyttOrt, nyttTelefonnr, nyttEpost);      
    kr.AddKund(nyKund);

}

public Kund updateKund(int nyttKundnr, String nyttPersorgnr,
        String nyttNamn, String nyttKontaktperson,
        String nyttAdress, int nyttPostnr,
        String nyttOrt, int nyttTelefonnr,
        String nyttEpost){
    Kund kund = new Kund(nyttKundnr, nyttPersorgnr, nyttNamn, nyttKontaktperson, nyttAdress, nyttPostnr, nyttOrt, nyttTelefonnr, nyttEpost);        
    kr.AddKund(kund);
    return kund;
}


public void addArtikel(int nyttArtikelnr, String nyttNamn, double nyttInpris, double nyttUtpris) {
    Artikel artikel = new Artikel(nyttArtikelnr, nyttNamn, nyttInpris, nyttUtpris);
    ar.addArtikel(artikel);
}

public Artikel updateArtikel(int nyttArtikelnr, String nyttNamn, double nyttInpris, double nyttUtpris) {
    Artikel artikel = new Artikel(nyttArtikelnr, nyttNamn, nyttInpris, nyttUtpris);
    ar.addArtikel(artikel);
    return artikel;
}
```

}

**Make article window:**

```
    public class NyArtikelWindow extends JFrame {
private JLabel lblArtikelnummer = new JLabel();

private JTextField txtArtikelnummer = new JTextField();
private JTextField txtArtikelnamn = new JTextField();
private JTextField txtInpris = new JTextField();
private JTextField txtUtpris = new JTextField();
private JTextField txtLeverantor = new JTextField();

private JLabel lblArtikelnamn = new JLabel();   
private JLabel lblInpris = new JLabel();
private JLabel lblUtpris = new JLabel();    
private JLabel lblLeverantor = new JLabel();

private JButton btnSpara = new JButton();
private JButton btnAvbryt = new JButton();

private Controller controller;
private UiController uicontroller;


public NyArtikelWindow(Controller controller, UiController uiController){
    this.controller = controller;
    this.uicontroller = uiController;   

    this.getContentPane().setLayout( null );
    this.setSize(new Dimension(432, 285));
    this.setTitle("Ny artikel");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    lblArtikelnummer.setText("Artikelnummer:");
    lblArtikelnummer.setBounds(new Rectangle(25, 35, 75, 15));
    txtArtikelnummer.setBounds(new Rectangle(105, 30, 110, 20));
    lblArtikelnamn.setText("Artikelnamn:");
    lblArtikelnamn.setBounds(new Rectangle(30, 80, 65, 15));
    txtArtikelnamn.setBounds(new Rectangle(105, 75, 280, 20));
    lblInpris.setText("Inpris:");
    lblInpris.setBounds(new Rectangle(60, 160, 34, 14));
    txtInpris.setBounds(new Rectangle(105, 155, 60, 20));
    lblUtpris.setText("Utpris:");
    lblUtpris.setBounds(new Rectangle(180, 160, 34, 14));
    txtUtpris.setBounds(new Rectangle(220, 155, 60, 20));
    lblLeverantor.setText("Leverantör:");
    lblLeverantor.setBounds(new Rectangle(30, 115, 60, 15));
    txtLeverantor.setBounds(new Rectangle(105, 110, 280, 20));
    btnSpara.setText("Spara");
    btnSpara.setBounds(new Rectangle(250, 215, 75, 21));
    btnSpara.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            btnSpara_actionPerformed(e);
        }
    });
    btnAvbryt.setText("Avbryt");
    btnAvbryt.setBounds(new Rectangle(330, 215, 75, 21));
    btnAvbryt.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              NyArtikelWindow.this.setVisible( false );
              NyArtikelWindow.this.dispose();
        }
    });
    this.getContentPane().add(btnAvbryt, null);
    this.getContentPane().add(btnSpara, null);
    this.getContentPane().add(txtLeverantor, null);
    this.getContentPane().add(lblLeverantor, null);
    this.getContentPane().add(txtUtpris, null);
    this.getContentPane().add(lblUtpris, null);
    this.getContentPane().add(txtInpris, null);
    this.getContentPane().add(lblInpris, null);
    this.getContentPane().add(txtArtikelnamn, null);
    this.getContentPane().add(lblArtikelnamn, null);
    this.getContentPane().add(txtArtikelnummer, null);
    this.getContentPane().add(lblArtikelnummer, null);
}

public void setVisibleOn() {
    setVisible(true);
}

public void btnSpara_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    String Artikelnr = txtArtikelnummer.getText();
    String nyttNamn = txtArtikelnamn.getText();
    String Inpris = txtInpris.getText();
    String Utpris = txtUtpris.getText();

    int nyttArtikelnr = Integer.parseInt(Artikelnr);
    double nyttInpris = Double.parseDouble(Inpris);
    double nyttUtpris = Double.parseDouble(Utpris);
    System.out.println(nyttArtikelnr+nyttNamn+nyttInpris+nyttUtpris);
    controller.addArtikel(nyttArtikelnr, nyttNamn, nyttInpris, nyttUtpris);
    txtArtikelnummer.setText(null); //btntest
    }
```

}

**ArtikelReg:**

```
     import java.util.*;

      public class ArtikelReg {

private HashMap<Integer, Artikel> artikelreg = new HashMap<Integer, Artikel> ();
private Controller controller;

public ArtikelReg(Controller controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
}

//lägg till en Artikel
public void addArtikel(Artikel artikel){
    artikelreg.put(artikel.getArtikelnr(), artikel);
}

//Ta bort Artikel
public void raderaArtikel(Kund RaderaKund){
    artikelreg.remove(RaderaKund);
}

//hämtar artikelregistret
public HashMap <Integer, Artikel> getArtikelreg(){
    return this.artikelreg;
}

public void setArtikelReg(HashMap<Integer, Artikel> artikelreg) {
    this.artikelreg = artikelreg;
}

//Hämtar en artikel ur registret
public Artikel visaArtikel(int Artikelnr){
    return artikelreg.get(Artikelnr);
}
```

}

**Show Articlewindow**

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class VisaArtiklarWindow extends JFrame {
private JLabel lblArtiklar = new JLabel();
private JTable tblArtiklar = new JTable(); 

private JButton btnNy = new JButton();
private JButton btnTabort = new JButton();
private JButton btnStang = new JButton();

private Controller controller;
private UiController uicontroller;

public VisaArtiklarWindow (Controller controller, UiController uiController) {

    this.controller = controller;
    this.uicontroller = uiController;

    this.getContentPane().setLayout( null );
    this.setSize(new Dimension(627, 388));
    this.setTitle( "Visa artiklar" );
    lblArtiklar.setText("Artiklar:");
    lblArtiklar.setBounds(new Rectangle(30, 30, 55, 15));


    tblArtiklar=new JTable();
    tblArtiklar.setBounds(new Rectangle(30, 50, 490, 250));
    tblArtiklar.setModel(controller.toTableModel());



    btnNy.setText("Ny...");
    btnNy.setBounds(new Rectangle(530, 50, 75, 21));
    btnNy.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            btnNy_actionPerformed(e);
        }
    });
    btnTabort.setText("Ta bort");
    btnTabort.setBounds(new Rectangle(530, 80, 75, 21));
    btnStang.setText("Stäng");
    btnStang.setBounds(new Rectangle(530, 320, 75, 21));
    this.getContentPane().add(btnStang, null);
    this.getContentPane().add(btnTabort, null);
    this.getContentPane().add(btnNy, null);
    this.getContentPane().add(tblArtiklar, null);
    this.getContentPane().add(lblArtiklar, null);
}

public void setVisibleOn() {
    setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Comment: you should reduce that large amount of code to the most significant parts

Answer (score 2):

First: a HashMap is unordered, you probably want a TreeMap, so the rows are ordered by article number.

A TableModel is easiest, but the event handling, needs a bit of attention so the JTable is notified of changes.

The problem is that if you change the map, the model is unaware, and especially concurrent access might give errors.
So the best way is to **replace** the map with your own TableModel (`implements Map<A, B>`).

```
public class MapTableModel<A, B> extends AbstractTableModel
        implements SortedMap<A, B> {

    private SortedMap<A, B> map = new TreeMap<A, B>();

    SortedMapTableModel() {
    }

    @Override
    public B put(A key, B value) {
        B old = map.put(key, value); // Delegate to an existing Map implementation.
        if (old == null) {
            fireTableStructureChanged(); // New row
        } else {
            fireTableDataChanged(); // Changed row
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you can do better, not implementing Map.

---

***Edit 1***

In order to let the JTable function (update properly), you have to make your changes in its TableModel.

So replace the Map variable with a TableModel variable. Use this variable to programmatical change the model.

The TableModel can internally use the Map as data holder. Now the DefaultTableModel does its own data containment. The TableModel interface is too abstract, especially it does not handle change events. The AbstractTableModel as base class is best.

To satisfy the AbstractTableModel, your IDE will allow you to implement abstract methods needed, and override some methods to make the model up.

For operating on your data you still need to add methods previously done on the map, like put(Integer articleno, Article art). Those methods can delegate all to map's methods, and fire an event that something has changed.

There should also be mentioned concurrent access issues: modifying the model while it being drawn: especially Concurrent Map, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html, but maybe too http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedSortedMap%28java.util.SortedMap%29

*If this is too much, extend `DefaultTableModel` instead and keep the data twice, in the DefaultTableMode and in the map field inside your TableModel.*

Comment: maby i am stupid, but i don't understand what you are saying joop. i see that you make it to a TreeMap instead but what about the @override. how do i get it to print out in a JTable

Comment: (You're not stupid, I realize that I did give a very fragmentary solution.) I'll edit my answer.